# Error in changing button visibility onClick

Tags: android, button, visibility, onclicklistener

I have a button which is called Check, I want it to be invisible and visible as I click each time on it, as If its visible and I clicked it will become invisible and verse vies !

But my code doesn't work ! any ideas ?

```
 Button Check ;
        @Override   
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
           setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        Check  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.checkButton);

           Check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View View) {



                if (View.getVisibility() == android.view.View.VISIBLE) 
                        View.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
                        else if (View.getVisibility() == android.view.View.INVISIBLE)
                            View.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
```

***In my activity its visible at the beginning and when I click on it, it become invisible, BUT when I click again it stays invisible !***

Comment: Can you add the error log please? Or specify what's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="abcd" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="abc"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>



public void abc(View v) {
    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

public void abcd(View v) {
    v.findViewById(R.id.button1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Invisible Items don't receive on-click event. So the only way you can receive a click on invisible is by receiving on some other view in place of the invisible view. The above solution wraps the button in a layout, so when button is invisible the on-click is passed on to layout, which handles the event and do accordingly. If you have a high usage of such layout you can also create a custom button with above mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to this,

```
Check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (v.isShown()) 
                        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                else
                        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
```

But i think problem is, when button goes invisible, you are not getting any click event on it. First make sure that `onClick` method get call when button is invisible.

**An invisible button will not dispatch any interaction event**. So instead of setting button's visibility to the invisible, you can set a transparent or blank background or something like that.

**But i personally believe, you should change your use-case because why one will click on the invisible button.**

Comment: How to make the on click get called when the button is invisible ?

Comment: You don't.  An invisible button isn't there.  The OS reserves space for it, but it can't be interacted with.